# How to crop images depending on the position of the face?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have such data:  x / y center of the face, height and width of the face, height and width of the original image. User uploads images where a face can be in perfectly different places and the aspect ratio of the image may be different.I determine if there is a face using openCV:

```
def crop_face(img, margin_x = 550, margin_y = 400):
image = cv2.imread(img)
height, width = image.shape[:2]
#print('width - {0}, height - {1}'.format(width, height))
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(FACE_DETECTOR_PATH)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.29, 5)
print ("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))
if len(faces) == 1:     
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:                 
        r = max(w, h) / 2
        centerx = x + w / 2
        centery = y + h / 2
        nx = int(centerx - r)
        ny = int(centery - r)
        nr = int(r * 2)
        print ('x - {0}, y - {1}, w - {2}, h - {3}'.format(x,y,w,h))
        print ('r - {0}, centerX - {1}, centerY - {2}, nx - {3}, ny - {4},nr - {5}'.format(r,centerx,centery,nx,ny, nr))
        margin_dict = get_normal_margin(margin_x, margin_y ,centerx, centery, height,width)
        margin_dict['x_max'] -= int(w/2);
        margin_dict['x_min'] -= int(w/2);
        margin_dict['y_max'] -= int(h/2);
        margin_dict['y_min'] -= int(h/2);
        roi_color = image[y-margin_dict['y_min']:y + h+margin_dict['y_max'], x-margin_dict['x_min']:x + w +margin_dict['x_max']]#y max, y min, x max, x min
        #roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        return roi_color
```

so trying to get the maximum allowable indent for x and y:

```
def get_normal_margin(margin_x, margin_y, center_x, center_y, height, width):
margin_to_return = {'y_max': margin_y, 'y_min': margin_y, 'x_max': margin_x, 'x_min': margin_x}
for x in range(int(center_x),  width - int(center_x)):      
    if(x < margin_x and x > 0):
        margin_to_return['x_max'] = x           
for x in reversed(range(int(center_x),  width - int(center_x))):
    if(x < margin_x and x > 0):     
        margin_to_return['x_min'] = x
for x in range(int(center_y),  height - int(center_y)):     
    if(x < margin_y and x > 0):
            margin_to_return['y_max'] = x
for x in reversed(range(int(center_y),  height - int(center_y))):
    if(x < margin_y and x > 0):
        margin_to_return['y_min'] = x           
return margin_to_return
```

but it does not work. some images cuts off nomral, some are completely abnormal.
here are examples:
[I give the entrance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtr0W.jpg)
[getting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3PZS.jpg)

[here is an example of what is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiUbc.jpg)

Am I on the right track or not at all?

Comment: `Rect(x,y,w,h) =>  cropped img[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Comment: @Kinght金 Sorry, but I do not understand. Where are the margins?